# Software update icon remains after update

Tags: 16.04

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and in the system tray the Software Update icon does not disappear once the update finished and I close the dialog box. How to solve this ?

Comment: Did you try simply logging out and back in?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried to update via the commang line but the icon remains.